# What is a good way to add python dependencies to a Docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, docker-compose

I am trying to integrate docker in to my django workflow and I have everything set up except one really annoying issue. If I want to add dependencies to my requirements.txt file I basically just have to rebuild the entire container image for those dependencies to stick.

For example, I followed the docker-compose example for django [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). the yaml file is set up like this:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

and the Docker file used to build the web container is set up like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

So when the image is built for this container requirements.txt is installed with whatever dependencies are initially in it.

If I am using this as my development environment it becomes very difficult to add any new dependencies to that requirements.txt file because I will have to rebuild the container for the changes in requirements.txt to be installed.

Is there some sort of best practice out there in the django community to deal with this? If not, I would say that docker looks very nice for packaging up an app once it is complete, but is not very good to use as a development environment. It takes a long time to rebuild the container so a lot of time is wasted.

I appreciate any insight . Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could mount `requirements.txt` as a volume when using `docker run` (untested, but you get the gist):

```
docker run container:tag -v /code/requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
```

Then you could bundle a script with your container which will run `pip install -r requirements.txt` before starting your application, and use that as your `ENTRYPOINT`. I love the custom entrypoint script approach, it lets me do a little extra work without needing to make a new container.

That said, if you're changing your dependencies, you're probably changing your application and you should probably make a new container and tag it with a later version, no? :)

Comment: Yeah, good idea. I could just have it install dependencies anytime the container starts up. I am going to give this a try.

Comment: @SpencerCooley Depending on how many dependencies you have you might want to make the container have the ones that you know you'll always have, and then just add the ability to add more. You wouldn't want the container to take several minutes to start up.

Comment: true, so the base image would have all the basics, and the startup script would install dependencies that I am using during the development process, like a sort of temporary dependency list. When I am ready to push it all out I can just move over the dependencies that I decide will be permanent to the system. Sometimes I am just experimenting with libraries that I don't end up using. It's like a dependency dev environment. final_requirments.txt  temp_requirements.txt

Comment: Yeah, there's many ways to skin a cat when you're working with docker. That's just one. You could also fork a new process in your container to get inside and change what it's doing, maybe install the dependencies or run the Django admin console, without doing much extra work: `docker exec -it /bin/bash`.

Comment: I was using docker exec before, but if you ever use `docker-compose run` for anything it wipes away what you previously did with exec.

Answer (score 3):

So I changed the yaml file to this:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: sh startup.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

I made a simple shell script startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#restart this script as root, if not already root
[ `whoami` = root ] || exec sudo $0 $*

pip install -r dev-requirements.txt

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and then made a dev-requirements.txt that is installed by the above shell script as sort of a dependency staging environment.

when I am satisfied with a dependency in dev-requirements.txt I will just move it over to the requirements.txt to be committed to the next build of the image. This gives me flexibility to play with adding and removing dependencies while developing.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to ignore what's currently the most common way to install python dependencies (`pip install -r requirements.txt`) and specify your requirements directly in the Dockerfile, effectively getting rid of the `requirements.txt` file. Additionally you get dockers layer caching for free.

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
# make sure you install requirements before the ADD, since everything after ADD is not cached
RUN pip install flask==0.10.1
RUN pip install sqlalchemy==1.0.6
...
ADD . /code/
```

If the docker container is the only way your application is ever run, then I would suggest you do it this way. If you want to support other means of setting up your code (e.g. virtualenv) then this is of course not for you and you should fall back to either using a requirements file or use a setup.py routine. Either way, I found this way to be most simple and straightforward without dealing with all the messed up python package distribution issues.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think this approach is flawed in that it doesn't ensure that someone else who builds from this dockerfile will get the same versions of libraries. i.e. it doesn't create a reproducible build.

Comment: It is a while ago I used docker like this. Can you elaborate?